# Strange HTML5 Drag&Drop behavior in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I`m implementing drag&drop in browser.

```
    var holder = document.getElementById('myholder');
    holder.ondragover = function () { 
      console.log("drag over event");  
    };
    holder.ondrop = function (e) {
    //do whatever
    }
```

Name of my PC is "PC1". The problem is, when I accessing url: loclahost/DragDropExample.htm and  dragging some text from other IE10 window onto my "holder", the ondragover event triggering fine. 
But when I accessing PC1/DragDropExample.htm and dragging some text onto "holder" area, the event is NOT triggering. It happens only in IE. Other browsers work fine. This is happening only when I drag from IE to IE.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a crossdomain drag and drop, you need to disable that security feature in ie settings. please refer to:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2581921